# Regex exclude specific charater

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the substring in-between two double quotes if present but I am only able to get the substring with the last double quote.
If the string has no double quotes, extract the substring

```
TEST STRINGS

"松嶋友里奈/ウェルキッズフォト" <service-info@wel-kids.jp>
SuperBacker Team <no-reply@backermail.com>
Medium Daily Digest <noreply@medium.com>
"Tory @ Flippa" <marketing@flippa.com>
CocaCola <team@cocacola.com>
```

`My regex for python: "(?!\")(.*?)(?!\")(?=\s\<)"`

```
ACTUAL RESULT

松嶋友里奈/ウェルキッズフォト**"** --> FAILED because of the double quote at the end
SuperBacker Team --> PASS
Medium Daily Digest --> PASS
Tory @ Flippa**"** --> FAILED because of the double quote at the end
CocaCola --> PASS
```

Why does my pattern include the double quote at the end but not at the beginning?

Comment: What about `re.sub(r'\s*<[^<>]*>', '', text).strip('"')`? See https://ideone.com/0LWLxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((?<=^)(?=[^\"])|(?<=\")).*[^\"](?=\"?\s\<)`

- `((?<=^)(?=[^\"])|(?<=\"))` either beginning of string - not followed by " (`(?<=^)(?=[^\"])`) or starting after " (`(?<=\")`)
- `.*[^\"]`anything that does not end in a double quote
- `(?=\"?\s\<)` followed by optionally a double quote and then  `<`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lutz. For the last 2 bullets of your answer, I don't understand why I need to put the double quote in each.

Comment: in the second to make sure your not having it as part of the match and in the third one so that we can make sure we match to the `< ` but have to include the `"` as that could still be there unmatched.